# Azure devops - Support if building iOS App with extensions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, visual-studio-app-center

My iOE source code hosted in VSTS using TFVC. I am evaluating automated build and release/publish to appstore. My iOS app has extensions.

I tried hosted macOS agent, but it doesn't support building of extensions.
I tried APP Center, but it doesn't support TFVC yet.

Any other options?

Comment: I am currently trying to do the same, as I need to build OneSignal with React Native. Did you have any luck?

Comment: MSFT member posted one solution in community forum, I didn't try it. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/512054/view.html

Comment: I am currently trying to integrate an app containing OneSignal with an Azure Pipeline and running into issues on the Xcode Build step caused from the OneSignal extension.